# I dont understand this java inheritance example

Tags: java, inheritance

I have been doing a mooc.fi course and im having a hard time understanding inheritance. This example in particular.

What does the program print?

```
public class Counter {

    public int addToNumber(int number) {
        return number + 1;
    }
    
    public int subtractFromNumber(int number) {
        return number - 1;
    }
}


public class SuperCounter extends Counter {

    @Override
    public int addToNumber(int number) {
        return number + 5;
    }
    
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    Counter counter = new Counter();
    Counter superCounter = new SuperCounter();
    int number = 3;
    number = superCounter.subtractFromNumber(number);
    number = superCounter.subtractFromNumber(number);
    number = counter.addToNumber(number);
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

Apparently this isnt 6.
Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: You do know that SuperCounter is a subclass of Counter.

Answer (score 4):

The result is 2. Let's see.

1. `Counter counter = new Counter();` gives us a `counter` with `addToNumber` and `subtractFromNumber` methods.
2. `Counter superCounter = new SuperCounter();` gives us a `superCounter` with `addToNumber` method.
3. `int number = 3;`
4. `number = superCounter.subtractFromNumber(number);` Since superCounter does not override the old subtractFromNumber, it subtracts 1. Now `number == 2`.
5. `number = superCounter.subtractFromNumber(number);` Same again, subtract 1, `number == 1`.
6. `number = counter.addToNumber(number);` This method adds 1. Now `number == 2`.

The result is `2`, as we expected.

Answer (score 1):

You have created 2 classes, and one inherits from the other (SuperCounter from Counter), which means that it inherits one method "subtractFromNumber" and overrides the other method "addToNumber".

Next, you create instances of these classes "counter" and "superCounter", while calling the method "subtractFromNumber" on the instance of the class "superCounter" 2 times and the method "addToNumber" on the other instance of the class "counter". But since you call the method "addToNumber" on the instance of the class "counter", respectively, the method of the class "Counter" is called.

According to the code, you get the answer "2":

1. int number = 3; // 3
2. number = superCounter.subtractFromNumber(number); // 3 - 1 = 2
3. number = superCounter.subtractFromNumber(number); // 2 - 1 = 1
4. number = counter.addToNumber(number);             // 1 + 1 = 2
5. System.out.println(number);                       // 2

Comment: The answer in the course is 8, so im not sure whats going on.

Comment: The course answer is incorrect. You can run the code for yourself to see the answer is 2. The answer could only be 8 if a) the subtracts weren't there and b) you were using a superCounter to addToNumber.

Comment: It must be a bug, i thought it was 2 at first, then maybe 6 but neither were accepted. They have a telegram feedback room so ill put it to them there.

Comment: Can i ask another question about inheritance in this thread or do i need to post a new question?

Comment: You need to write a new question.